# R's replicate and do.call functions equivalent in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Suppose that you want construct a pd.DataFrame and you want to get different numbers every-time you increase replicate number in it. (Please Scroll down for Reproducible example in R)

I would like to get same output with Python but I dont know how to get there!

If you consider this simple pd.Dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
        'a':[np.random.normal(0.27,0.01,5),np.random.normal(1,0.01,5)]})

df      
                                                          a
        0  [0.268297564096, 0.252974100195, 0.27613413347...
        1  [0.996267313891, 1.00497494738, 1.022271644, 1...
```

I dont know why the data look like this. When I do only one `np.random.normal` I am getting this,

```
        a
0  0.092309
1  0.085985
2  0.083635
3  0.081582
4  0.104096
```

Sorry, I cannot explain this behaviour.I am new in `pandas` maybe you could explain this.

Ok, lets get back to original question;

If you want to generate second group of numbers and I guess I should use `np.repeat`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({['a':np.repeat(np.random.normal(0.10,0.01,5),np.random.normal(0.10,0.01,5)])})


df
Out[59]: 
           a
0   0.090305
1   0.090305
2   0.109092
3   0.109092
4   0.101706
5   0.101706
6   0.087357
7   0.087357
8   0.099094
9   0.099094
10  0.101595
11  0.101595
12  0.100343
13  0.100343
14  0.085380
15  0.085380
16  0.102118
17  0.102118
18  0.107328
19  0.107328
```

But np.repeat is just generating the same numbers twice is not the output what I want.

here is the approach in R case,

```
df <- data.frame(y = do.call(c,replicate(n = 2,
                                    expr = c(rnorm(5,0.10,0.01),rnorm(5,1,0.01)),
                                    simplify = FALSE)),gr = rep(seq(1,2),each=10))



         y     gr
1  0.11300203  1
2  0.11840556  1
3  0.09420799  1
4  0.10480623  1
5  0.08561427  1
6  1.00076001  1
7  1.00035891  1
8  1.00936751  1
9  1.00050563  1
10 1.00564799  1
11 0.09415217  2
12 0.10794155  2
13 0.11534605  2
14 0.08806740  2
15 0.12394189  2
16 0.99330066  2
17 0.98254134  2
18 0.99828079  2
19 1.00786526  2
20 0.97864180  2
```

Basically in R you can do this in pretty straightforward. But I guess in python one has to write a function for it.

In R you can generate normal distribution of numbers with `rnorm` and on `numpy` we can do that with `np.random.normal`. But I could not find any built in function for especially `do.call`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, in R you do not need `do.call()`:

```
set.seed(95)
df <- data.frame(y = c(rnorm(10,0.10,0.01), rnorm(10,1,0.01)),
                 gr = c(rep(0,10), rep(1,10)))
df
#             y gr
# 1  0.08970880  1
# 2  0.08384474  1
# 3  0.09972121  1
# 4  0.09678872  1
# 5  0.11880371  1
# 6  0.10696807  1
# 7  0.09135123  1
# 8  0.08925115  1
# 9  0.10994412  1
# 10 0.09769954  1
# 11 1.01486420  2
# 12 1.01533145  2
# 13 1.01454184  2
# 14 0.99125878  2
# 15 0.98222886  2
# 16 1.00128867  2
# 17 0.97588819  2
# 18 0.98216944  2
# 19 0.99982671  2
# 20 0.99090591  2
```

And with Python pandas/numpy, consider concatenating arrays using [`np.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(89)
df = pd.DataFrame({'y': np.concatenate([np.random.normal(0.1,0.01,10), 
                                        np.random.normal(1,0.01,10)]),
                   'gr': [1]*10 + [2]*10})
print(df)    
#     gr         y
# 0    1  0.083063
# 1    1  0.099979
# 2    1  0.095741
# 3    1  0.097444
# 4    1  0.096942
# 5    1  0.100405
# 6    1  0.099316
# 7    1  0.087978
# 8    1  0.098175
# 9    1  0.091204
# 10   2  0.997568
# 11   2  1.006740
# 12   2  1.003449
# 13   2  0.993747
# 14   2  0.997935
# 15   2  0.991284
# 16   2  0.991299
# 17   2  1.003981
# 18   2  0.993347
# 19   2  1.001337
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you wanted, but you could use a `for` loop and generate the second set of random numbers as shown below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_items([('a' , np.append([np.random.normal(0.10,0.01,5) for _ in xrange(2)], 
                                             [np.random.normal(1,0.01,5) for _ in xrange(2)]
                                            ))])
```

df is then

```
           a
0   0.105469
1   0.091046
2   0.091626
3   0.104579
4   0.110971
5   0.076754
6   0.104674
7   0.096062
8   0.103571
9   0.089955
10  0.978489
11  0.997081
12  1.009864
13  1.000333
14  0.998483
15  1.010685
16  1.004473
17  1.001833
18  1.007723
19  0.999845
```

Comment: wow I knew that it is way more complex than creating the same data frame with `pandas`. Can we add `gr` column also ?

Comment: and I would be grateful if you can explain `for _ xrange(2)` ? and are there any reason for the thing I mentioned in OP's first part?